# JavaScript: Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response when request through gitlab api

Tags: google-chrome, http, get, xmlhttprequest, gitlab-api

I have successfully received the user's id through gitlab api, but when I tried to receive the project list of the user, chrome returns CORB.

I have successfully received the id and all other user info with GitLab api v4. But when I was trying to receive the repo list of the user, I received the CORB block and get nothing on the response text. I can see the data in json form if the website address is entered directly. If I use jQuery.getJSON directly, it will ask me to add X-Requested-With or Origin to the header, which I don't know how to achieve.

```
                        var target = 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/'+doc.data().gitlab_id+'/projects?callback=?';
                        console.log(target);
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.onreadystatechange = process;
                        xhr.open("GET", target, true);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('responseType', 'text/plain');
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                        xhr.send();
                        function process() {
                            console.log(xhr);
```

I expect to get the json data, but now the response text is empty and it returns a message below:

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/USER_ID/projects?callback=jQuery11130057655514217979986_1563975117007&_=1563975117008 with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who faces the same problem:

Try adding 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' right before your request url.

For example, you can use 
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth2_access_token=' + access_token;
to get info from linkedin without being troubled by cors policy.